# AngularJS + ASP.NET MVC - Can you use both under "/"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-routing, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

I want to serve my AngularJS SPA from "/" and for that reason I have disabled default route and am using

```
    // this action does not 'fire' due to Angular's routing...
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Test",
        url: "Test",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Test" },
        namespaces: new[] { "My.WebApp.Controllers" }
    );

    // Index view has no layout and contains Angular SPA
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "AngularJs-SPA",
        url: "{*catchall}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
        namespaces: new[] { "My.WebApp.Controllers" }
    );
```

I am also using following angular app config block

```
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

      $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/404' });
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }])
```

My question is can I still somehow have a regular server side page that responds to MVC action (in this case /Home/Test)?
The issue I am seeing is that Angular takes over the routing and even if I define additional route (either before or after the angular route), Angular sees it as "otherwise" route...

Few (undesirable) solutions

- specify each angular app routes in MVC instead of {*catchall}
- move angular spa to a non root action (e.g. /app)

Answer (score 1):

You could set the $window.location directly from `otherwise`:

```
myApp
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                template: "<h1>Welcome!</h1>"
            })
            .otherwise({
                template: " ",
                controller: function($location, $window) {
                    $window.location.href = $location.path();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

Comment: I tried this and it causes 'infinite loop' whereas page /Home/Test is constantly being loaded with 200 OK....

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but this is now I'm doing it and it's working pretty well.

Note in the .config that I'm doing html5Mode(false).  That keeps the URL on the same page and adds a /# that keeps the MVC router from taking over.  That also means that you need to add that /# in your links to ensure you can bookmark the page and get back to it (pass through server side routing).

Also, due to the way the MVC router hordes pages and restricts access to CSHTML files, I am using a server side method to get the html partial views.  Some of these views use HTML Helpers, so I left them as CSHTML files instead of putting them in an unrestricted static views bin.

MVC Routing

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Direct",
            url: "{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

-- Method in Home (or base) Controller

```
    public PartialViewResult GetPartial(string p)
    {
        return PartialView(string.Format("~/Views/Home/Partials/{0}.cshtml", p));
    }
```

-- Angular Code

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

    $routeProvider
        .when("/", { templateUrl: "/GetPartial?p=Dashboard", controller: "DashboardController" })
        .when("/NewWidget/", { templateUrl: "/GetPartial?p=NewWidget", controller: "NewWidgetController" })
        .when("/Widget/:widgetId", { templateUrl: "/GetPartial?p=Widget", controller: "WidgetController" })
        .when("/Widget/Edit/:widgetId", { templateUrl: "/GetPartial?p=WidgetEdit", controller: "EditWidgetController" })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });

});

app.controller('DashboardController', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $q, $sce, $location, $routeParams) {

    $scope.SetPath = function (route) {
            if (!route) return;

            route = route.replace('/#', '');

            if (route[0] == '/')
                $location.path(route);
            else
                $location.path('/' + route);
        };
});
```

-- HTML

Option A)

```
<a ng-click="SetPath('/Widget?widgetId=w1234')">View Widget 1234</a>
```

Option B)

```
<a href="/#/Widget?widgetId=w1234">View Widget 1234</a>
```

Comment: "Note in the .config that I'm doing html5Mode(false)"...Unfortunately, this is a dealbreaker for me...